# What actions done by thread will cause other threads and the whole process to terminate?

Tags: operating-system, pthreads

I was encountering bugs in my program which caused the whole process to terminate, while I debugged through my program and follow the `Task Manager` I could see my process terminated while running a certain thread.

I stepped through this thread and apparently I used `exit()` which caused the problem. I changed to `pthread_exit()` yet again I had the same issue, it turned out to be that the specific thread also had an illegal operation: `division by zero`.

- pthread_exit
- pthread_cancel
- exit
- illegal action
- main thread return

When will those cause the process to terminate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 |                     | thread | process                        |
 -----------------------------------------------------------------
 | pthread_exit        | finish | finish iff last running thread |
 | pthread_cancel      | finish | finish iff last running thread |
 | exit()              | finish | finish                         |
 | Illegal operation   | finish | finish                         |
 | thread finishes     | finish | finish iff last running thread |
 | main thread finishes| finish | finish                         |
```

`return` is a wrapper function that contain `exit` `sys_call`, this is why the whole threads are terminated as well.

`CPUs` tend to throw an exception interrupt,
on things like **division by zero**, or **dereferencing a NULL pointer**. Causing the execution of the program to halt and return control to the OS to handle the event. The program may be terminated, 
all resources freed depending on the OS.